# DataTable group by separated by comma

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by

I have a datatable that looks like the following

```
cname  tname  text        allowgroupping
A      M      good        Yes
A      M      bad         Yes
A      M      ugly        Yes
B      N      sick        No
B      N      lovely      No
C      R      pathatic    Yes
```

I want to group the datatable by the first column `cname` so the result will look like

```
cname  tname      text                 allowgroupping
    A      M      good,bad,ugly        Yes
    B      N      sick,lovely          No
    C      R      pathatic             Yes
```

I have done it by looping each column and doing a lot of checks, but how can I do it using LINQ and save the result to a datatable?

Comment: This SO post has your answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/7325306/1246574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    var query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                group row by row["cname"] into g
                select new {    cname = g.Key,
                                tname = g.First()["tname"] ,
                                text = String.Join(", ", g.Select(r=>r["text"].ToString()).ToArray()),
                                allowgrouping = g.First()["allowgroupping"]
                };

    foreach (var row in query)
    {
        resultDataTable.Rows.Add(row.cname, row.tname, row.text, row.allowgrouping);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to group the table per:

```
var groupedDB =
  from entry in dataTable
  group entry by entry.cName into entryGroup
  select new
  {
    cName = entryGroup.Key,
    tName = entryGroup.First().tName,
    text = String.Join(",", entryGroup.Select(_=>_.text)),
    allowGrouping = entryGroup.First().allowGrouping
  };
```

Of course, once you do that you'll see that you're making some bold assumptions about the `tName` and `allowGrouping` columns. Be sure that you mean to. If not, you should group by all three columns instead of just the `cName`.